# How to enable notifications for the assignee of new issues in SonarQube?

Tags: sonarqube

We want every user to get an email about new issues they introduced in this analysis.

I found this request here, saying it should already have been possible:
http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-2747

Is it a matter of configuring SonarQube or did they remove the feature in the meanwhile? Unfortunately this is not documented anywhere and the Jira request does not say anything about the solution itself.

[EDIT]

**What I want is following scenario:**

1. A commits a new issue.
2. B commits a new issue.  SonarQube analysis is run. (nobody actively changed something; e.g. reassigned issues)
3. A gets a mail saying that he introduced **1 new issue**.
4. B gets a mail saying that she introduced **1 new issue**.
5. A and B can (if they subscribed) get another mail saying that there are **two new issues** in total.

[/EDIT]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the feature I'm looking for will be in the release 5.2:

https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-6106

Comment: Besides the mail notification, I want also to be notified via IRC channel. Best would be if the notification goes directly to the IRC user who caused it (so the user has to specify the IRC nickname somewhere). Is there maybe a plugin for SonarQube with these features?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to receive a notification on new issues, but 2 conditions have to be met:

1. The SonarQube Server has to be set up to send emails: Administration > General Settings > Email.
2. *The user* must subscribe to notifications, which can be done from the user profile. Click on your avatar in the top-right.

You cannot, as an administrator, proactively subscribe your users. They must choose to be notified.

## EDIT:

It is possible in 5.1 (you don't mention your version) to receive notification of any new issues. Your #5

It will be possible "soon" to receive notifications on new issues you introduced - your #3, #4

Comment: sure. But thats just a general notification about all new issues.
We are working in a team of 20+ people here committing on different branches of a huge code base. So there are always new issues.
We don't want to get bothered about issues other people have to fix. I can look them up on the webpage anyway. I want more specific mails only when I was blamed to have introduced a new finding.

Comment: Then the "Changes in issues assigned to me or reported by me" notification is what you want. :-)

Comment: @AndreasScharf what is your SQ version ?

Comment: Its SonarQube Version 5.1.1
I have the option "Changes in issues assigned to me or reported by me" enabled. 
But it seems, that it is only sending mails if someone changed the assignment to me actively. Or something else within an issue already assigned to me changed.
**I don't get an email** when SonarQube auto assigns the issue.

Maybe there is something wrong with our installation!?

Comment: We have the same problem, we've selected notifications for "Changes in issues assigned to me or reported by me" and we still don't get any notifications when an issue is assigned to the user.

We've checked that email setup works correctly using the test email.

Comment: btw it is bad stackoverflow to leave only a link as the answer as links break. As such your first link is broken.